# JavaScript number comparison giving wrong results

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am attempting to create a 3 field search, hiding and showing cards depending on if they meet the criteria.
query1, and query2 work just fine, but for some reason, query3 doesn't work as intended.
I used a console log to figure out what is happening and the result are baffling.

```
const marketSearchFunction = function() {
  const query1 = $('#market-search').val().toLowerCase();
  const query2 = parseFloat($('#market-min').val());
  const query3 = parseFloat($('#market-max').val());
  let boolean1 = false
  let boolean2 = isNaN(query2) ? true : false
  let boolean3 = isNaN(query3) ? true : false
  $('.market-frame').each(function(){
    const price = parseFloat($(this).find('.price').data('value'))
    boolean1 = $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(query1) !== -1
    boolean2 = (boolean2 ? boolean2 : (price >= query2))
    boolean3 = (boolean3 ? boolean3 : (price <= query3))
    console.log(price, query3, boolean3, (price <= query3))
    showCard($(this), (boolean1 === boolean2 === boolean3))
  });
}
```

Here is the console log output

- NaN 1500 false false
- (2) 1500 1500 true true
- 2000 1500 true false
- 1800 1500 true false

**Why does the system set boolean3 to true, when the value of the comparison is false?**

1800 is NOT less than 1500, yet it sets it to TRUE.
I restarted the server, I moved the code about.
I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Looks like `isNaN(query3) ` is returning `true`, setting `boolean3` to `true`, which in turn, set `boolean3` to `true`. therefore `price` is never evaluated against `query3`. I would advise setting more `console.log` points to see the value at each step.

Comment: FYI `boolean1 === boolean2 === boolean3` doesn't check whether all three values are the same but rather whether the result of `boolean1 === boolean2` equals `boolean3`, which is different. Consider the following which is `true`: `false === false === true`

Comment: @Twisty I checked the console for isNaN(query3) and it does come back as false. So the system knows it is a number and would go on to the comparison.

Comment: @FelixKling It seems so obvious now looking at those comparisons again. Not sure why I didn't use && initially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a direct answer to your question but hopefully a fix for your problem.

Regardless of the logic errors in your current code, I think you can simplify your logic and therefore make it less error prone and easier to reason about. I believe the core issue is that you are sharing the `boolean*` variables across all iterations.

Also use meaningful variable names:

```
const marketSearchFunction = function() {
  const query = $('#market-search').val().toLowerCase();
  let minPrice = parseFloat($('#market-min').val());
  let maxPrice = parseFloat($('#market-max').val());

  // Using -Infinity and Infinity lets us keep the price comparison
  // logic simple
  if (isNaN(minPrice)) minPrice = -Infinity;
  if (isNaN(maxPrice)) maxPrice = Infinity;

  $('.market-frame').each(function(){
    const price = parseFloat($(this).find('.price').data('value'));
    const shouldShow =
      $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(query1) !== -1
      && price >= minPrice
      && price <= maxPrice;

    showCard($(this), shouldShow);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following.

```
const marketSearchFunction = function() {
  var query = [
    $('#market-search').val().toLowerCase(),
    parseFloat($('#market-min').val()),
    parseFloat($('#market-max').val())
  ];
  var bool = [
    false,
    true,
    true
  ];
  console.log(query, bool);
  $('.market-frame').each(function(i, el) {
    var price = parseFloat($(el).find('.price').data('value'));
    bool[0] = $(el).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(query[0]) !== -1;
    bool[1] = bool[1] && price >= query[1];
    bool[2] = bool[2] && price <= query[2];
    console.log(price, bool);
    showCard($(el), bool[0] && bool[1] && bool[2]);
  });
}
```

It looks like you are trying to perform some type of validation.

Remember the following logic:

| A | B | A && B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| true | true | true |
| true | false | false |
| false | true | false |
| false | false | false |

As you iterate over the items, you can setting the value using this logic. It's faster than the Ternary Operator, I think.

I might be a little confused by your process, but I think this will help you.